# How can i run step-by-step execution in Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4

How can I run an app step-by-step in Xcode so that I may find where my app crashes ?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376199/xcode-4-debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go ahead with **Breakpoints**. [[Reference]](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH3-SW38).